# django 'polls' tutorial - moving on from one poll to another

Tags: python, django

So I've finished the django tutorial but one thing I don't like about it is that you cant click through to the next poll when you answer one. For example if your `localhost:8000/polls/` page looked like:

```
red or white?
black or blue?
Who is your favourite Beatle?
```

then I'd like to be able to answer the first poll (red or white) then move onto the 'black or blue' question from that button that normally says vote again.

I'm very new to python and django but I'm guessing it just requires a tweak like a "+1" into the `{% url 'polls:detail' poll.id %}">Vote again?` statement in `polls/results.html`.

What's the tweak?
Thanks,

Comment: Do you save answers to db, can multiple users vote?

Comment: all the questions are radio buttons so yes the db keeps a total of what answer was submitted and how many times. not sure how im going to do this for an open-ended question though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Poll object has a DateField or DateTimeField that is not nullable:

```
pub_date = models.DateTimeField(...)
```

Then you can get the next object based upon that datetime with the `get_next_by_FOO` method that is [automatically added](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_next_by_FOO) by django.

In your template you could then have:

```
{% with next=object.get_next_by_pub_date %}
    {% if next %}
        <a href="{% url 'polls:detail' next.id %}">next</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `results` view you can add a variable `next_question` like:

```
next_question = None
try:
    next_question = Question.objects.filter(id__gt=question_id)[:1][0]
except IndexError:
    pass
```

And in template:

```
{% if next_question %}
    <a href="{% url 'polls:detail' next_question.id %}">Next question</a>
{% endif %}
```